# Custom webservices on NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way to upload custom web services to the netsuite platform to add custom business processing logic? 
Looked into SuiteApp/SuiteBundles and all they provide is a way to extend existing records/forms/lists, add custom scripts so on and so forth. Havent been able to find information on integrating external webservices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Restlets to create Custom Functionality in a particular Netsuite account and than the restlet can be accessed externally.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I am looking for is to implement a Java WebService that in turn uses some external libraries for added functionality. The SuiteScript will then invoke this WebService. So, I am looking for a way to package the JavaWS along with the dependent 3rd party libraries and make this available to SuiteScripts. From what I see, RESTlets are suitescripts that are exposed as REST end-points and I dont see a way to use external libraries within RESTlets.

Comment: You can't host anything on Netsuite other than the suite scripts. You should try to do as many thing as possible within Netsuite. But you can certainly host a JAVAWS outside Netsuite and than access it within Suitescripts using nlapiRequestURL

Answer (score 0):

If you want the logic of web-service written in Java / .Net then you can use [SuiteTalk](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/platform/developer/suitetalk.shtml) to communicate with NetSuite. Where all the processing is done in your service and you use API to get/set data to/from NetSuite.

But on the flip side you have to host this service on your end.. NetSuite can only host web-services written in the form of RestLet / SuiteLet.